# fastest way to group sum in R

Tags: r, string, text

### Input

### df1

```
colA           colB
23            google
3423    google facebook
234          facebook
45654         myspace
```

### df2

```
colA    colB    colC                                      colD
176393  177410  I use google                                1
903051  566590  I don't use google                          2
833826  783799  He ilksdfjs google facebook in kjhfkjdhf    3
61633   724094  I don't like facebook                       4
201540  422083  ahsfhds alsjkd fioawe myspace               5
847378  238557  kjsgjkf google                              6
766361  991353  ldkfjslj skjfv facebook                     7
924458  132127  dlkfjsflk slkdf lsisre snfh google          8
67391   267390  slkjfalj myspace                            9
600908  908724  dlfkj myspace google facebook               10
```

### output Intermediate

```
colA        colB               output col
23          google             1+2+3+6+8+10
3423        google facebook    3+10
234         facebook           3+4+7+10
45654       myspace            5+9+10
```

### output df1

```
colA         colB             output col
23           google             30
3423         google facebook    13
234          facebook           24
45654        myspace            24
```

currently i am using :

```
df1$output_col <-sapply(df1$colB,function(x)sum(df2$colD[grepl(paste0("\\b",x,"\\b"), df2$colD)]))
```

It is giving me desired output but at the same time taking way too much time. I have a fairly large dataset and need to reduce the runtime.

Please suggest an optimized way, if there is any.

Comment: I suggest you use `library(data.table)` for efficiency.

Comment: @Sotos Can you share how can i use that while using grepl function ?

Comment: can you make your example reproducible? use `dput()`

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with `ddply` function of the `plyr` [package](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plyr/docs/ddply)? It lets you create dataframes aggregating information for example you could merge the two data frames as a pre-processing step and then do

```
ddply(new_dataframe, .(colA,colB), summarize, output = sum(colD))
```

**UPDATE**

Steps:

```
df2$colC = as.character(df2$colC)
df2$term = regmatches(df2$colC,regexpr("google| google facebook|facebook|myspace",df2$colC))
ddply(df2,.(term), summarize,output =sum(colD))
```

Just find a generic regex expression to use all values in `levels(df1$colC)`

Comment: Can you share answer in steps. Perhaps taking input datasets into account.

Comment: Thanks for the input but it is taking same time as the method :
`df1$output_col <-sapply(df1$colB,function(x)sum(df2$colD[grepl(paste0("\\b",x,"\\b"), df2$colD)]))`

I am looking for something faster.